# How to setup a new user and grant them contributor rights

Tags: azure

What is the best way to setup a new user and grant them contributor rights to a new Azure tenancy?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Azure Active Directory and Create a new user:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal-assign-users

Grant the contributor access to the user:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal